# Can I use drawing js libraries with NativeScript?

Tags: html5-canvas, drawing, nativescript, paperjs, angular2-nativescript

Can I use drawing js libraries with NativeScript ?

sample of drawing libraries
http://paperjs.org/
http://www.pixijs.com/
http://fabricjs.com/

Note: 
Some use WEBGL
some use html canvas
some use SVG

Answer (score 2):

Quite possible but i would not use them if i could as there would be probably problem with performance as you will need to implement them inside webview and not as native element

Comment: To piggyback on this answer, you can use them. I'm assuming they're all tied to the browser/DOM in some fashion so as @MarekMaszay said, you would end up putting them inside a webview since they are not native drawing libraries for Android or iOS. If you want native drawing then you could find a native drawing library and implement that in your nativescript app for native rendering.

Comment: @BradMartin assume that we have a web and an android application
can I make 2 drawing component one for the web with canvas and the other with native android library 
and share all the other code for the two applications

Comment: Yes if you're going to be sharing a lot of code I'd suggest NativeScript with angular but plain NativeScript is great also. So you could use two different approaches for the drawing.